# How to Modal close in whole screen click

Tags: javascript

```js
var search = $(".btn-search-button");
var close = $(".close-search");
var overlay = $(".overlay");
search.click(function () {
  filter_show();
});
close.click(function () {
  filter_hide();
});
function filter_show() {
  $(".btn-search-filter-div").addClass("filtered");
  overlay.show(20);
}
function filter_hide() {
  $(".btn-search-filter-div").removeClass("filtered");
  overlay.hide();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a 'click away listener?' Where if you click outside of the modal it closes the modal?

Comment: We need to see the way to open the modal. Can you show that code?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', function(e) { if (!e.target.matches('.btn-search-button')){ filter_hide() }});` not teseted

Comment: click on filter button & this time only click on close button to close, i need close whole screen to click close sidebar

Comment: @zer00ne, clicking are working, but, the click in modal also close no any field selected

Comment: http://rms.rkwebs.xyz/frontend/web/
click on filter button

Comment: Yeah, nothing of the sort is there. Check your link.

Comment: Replace `'.btn-search-button'` with the selector of the actual modal. Maybe `".overlay"`?

Comment: @zer00ne, Modal cannot opan add the ".overlay" class

Comment: @zer00ne, can you provide me email id so i can better understand

Comment: @JoelHager, yes i can click anywhere clickable when open the modal

Comment: @zer00ne, when open the modal & click on checkbox, so modal close on checkbox ?

Comment: var trigger = $('.navbar-toggler'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
       
     isClosed = false;
    
    trigger.click(function () {
      hamburger_cross();      
    });
    
    function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = false;
      }
  }

Comment: var search = $('.btn-search-button');
var close = $('.close-search');
var overlay = $('.overlay');

search.click(function(){

  filter_show();
});
close.click(function(){
  filter_hide();
});

function filter_show(){
  $('.btn-search-filter-div').addClass('filtered');
  overlay.show(20);
}
function filter_hide(){
  $('.btn-search-filter-div').removeClass('filtered');
   overlay.hide();
}
$(document).on('click', function(e) { if (!e.target.matches('.btn-search-button')){ filter_hide() }});

Comment: The whole code is there

Comment: @smitkansara - please don't put blocks of code in comments - put it in your question, formatted, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that `$('.overlay')` is the backdrop for the modal, and you already have that hide() function. Without seeing the HTML and all the relevant code, this is just a best guess.

```
var overlay = $(".overlay");
overlay.click(function () {
  filter_hide();
});
```